# Is there any way to get full screen video url android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-webview, chromium

When I full screen video in android 5.0 form webview it return me "android_webview.FullScreenView" . is there any way to get video url from this object ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode. It will help you. For more details please check below link

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply .actually i am trying to get video url from full screen video view , but i can't access chromium classes